# why input isn't being taken as i wanted?

Tags: c, string, input

In this program i want to get a input where will be a string with some int.if no values were not given then, the program will just show the total amount.

But here, in the 1st case if i use a string with number,then there is 2 output.

Example input:

> 4
>
> donate  100
>
> report
>
> donate 500

Example output:

> 0
>
> 100
>
> 100
>
> 0

**But notice here i got chance of 3 times to input string,but output is 4 time.**
**So, can anyone tell me why this program acting weird?**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int T, total=0, val=0;
    char  input1[20];

    scanf("%d",&T);

    while(T--)
    {
        scanf(" %s",input1);
        val=-1;

        val=atoi(input1);
        total+=val;

        printf("\nInput=\"%s\" val=\"%d\"\n", input1, val);

        if(val != -1)
            printf("%d\n",total);

    }
}
```

Comment: `scanf(" %s", input1);` reads till the next whitespace. first `scanf` will read `donate` and the second `100`.

Comment: Why not just add a line of code to log what's in `input1` and what's in `val` right before the `if` and figure it out yourself?

Comment: ya i did that,the val is showing correct info.but output is coming unexpectedly

Comment: @mahinhossen Are you saying `val` was `-1` and you were still getting output? Your `if` pretty clearly prevents that.

Comment: got it, i should have checked that.thanks for the help @DavidSchwartz

Comment: is there any way? so that i can add "donate 100" in a string?cause as @Osiris said, string is taking "donate" and "100" seperately.

Comment: Don't you want them separate? You want to ignore the "donate" and process the "100", right? So you want them separate.

Comment: @mahinhossen If you want to read a string until new line you should use `scanf(" %[^\n]s",input1);`

Comment: i don't want them seperate. for example, if i input "donate 100", then i want to total would be 100. @DavidSchwartz

Comment: @mahinhossen Right, so you do want them separate. You want to be able to ignore the "donate" and process the "100". That's most easily done if they're separate. If they're together, you'd just have to separate them because you want to handle the two things differently.

Comment: can u suggest any way to do that?i used scanf(" %[^\n]s"). but it isn't acting on that val.cause it remains -1.@DavidSchwartz

Comment: @mahinhossen Your `scanf` is fine. You just need to add code to ignore the input if it's not a number. Your choice of `atoi` was not a good one, since it has no error detection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add logging and the answer will be obvious:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int T, total=0, val=-1;
    char  input1[20];

    scanf("%d",&T);

    while(T--)
    {
        scanf(" %s",input1);
        val=-1;

        val=atoi(input1);
        total+=val;

        printf("\nInput='%s' val='%d'\n", input1, val);

        if(val != -1)
            printf("%d\n",total);

    }
}
```

Then run it and give it your input:

```
4
donate 100

Input='donate' val='0'
0

Input='100' val='100'
100
report

Input='report' val='0'
100
donate 500

Input='donate' val='0'
100
```

As you can see, your expectation that you'd somehow get a `-1` value in `val` if `atoi` wasn't given a number is incorrect.